# Seaborn PairGrid with swarm plots

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, swarmplot

I have a dataset (kinda) like this:

```
f1  f2  f3     value
4   2   3      0.927252
1   3   0      0.153415
0   1   1      0.928820
1   0   4      0.933250
0   4   3      0.397307
...
```

I want to produce a Seaborn [`PairGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html) with [`stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html)s with jitter or [`swarmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html)s for each pair of features `f1`, `f2` and `f3`, and use `value` for the `hue`.

Plots in the diagonals should look something like this:

[image: 1D strip plot]

Which I created with:

```
df = ...  # My dataset
sns.stripplot("f1", "f1", "value", data=df, jitter=True,
              palette=sns.light_palette("red", len(df)),
              hue_order=sorted(df["value"])).legend().remove()
```

And off-diagonal plots would be like this:

[image: 2D strip plot]

Which, likewise, I made with:

```
df = ...  # My dataset
sns.stripplot("f1", "f2", "value", data=df, jitter=True,
              palette=sns.light_palette("red", len(df)),
              hue_order=sorted(df["value"])).legend().remove()
```

What I'm trying, therefore, is:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = ...  # My dataset
g = sns.PairGrid(df, hue="value", palette=sns.light_palette("red", len(df)),
                 hue_order=sorted(df["value"]), vars=df.columns[:-1])
g.map_diag(lambda x, **kwargs: sns.stripplot(x, x, **kwargs), jitter=True)
g.map_offdiag(sns.stripplot, jitter=True)
```

However, this is yielding:

[image: Strip plot pair grid]

I don't really know what I'm missing here. I can still make the plots my self and put them into my own subplots, but that's the whole point of the pair grid. Are these kinds of plots not supported on a grid for some reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike the name may suggest, the `hue` parameter does not define a color. It may be better to think of it as something like "further dimension" or similar. While in many cases this further dimension is visualized by color, it is not necessarily true for every plot.

In order to get the desired PairGrid, we may leave the hue out, such that all values are shown.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5, size=(4**3, 3)), columns=["f1", "f2", "f3"])
df["value"] = np.random.rand(len(df))

g = sns.PairGrid(df, vars=df.columns[:-1])
g.map(sns.stripplot, jitter=True, size=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The point here is that the `hue` of the `PairGrid` is something completely different than the `hue` of the `stripplot`. You may indeed use the hue of the stripplot itself to colorize the points in each individual plot, while the `hue` of the `PairGrid` rather divides the dataframe into further categories, one category per hue value; this is unwanted here, because the value column in the dataframe contains a continuous variable and you would end up with as many categories as different values in that column.

Comment: Okay, it's interesting that it works without the `hue` parameter. But get this, if I do this `g.map(sns.stripplot, jitter=True, size=3, hue=df["value"], palette=sns.light_palette("red", len(df)), hue_order=sorted(df["value"]))` I actually get what I wanted. For me this is an inconsistent behavior... But maybe you can explain a bit what you mean when say the the hue is just a "further dimension" and not necessarily color?

Comment: I tried to explain a bit better in the answer. Are you sure that the plot you get is then actually correct in the sense that the point's color corresponds to its value, or is it just any color from the palette?

Comment: Well it's actually hard to tell 100% for sure, but yeah I think so, [here](https://imgur.com/a/lYVSC) is an screenshot for a simpler case (two features and 10 data points) comparing the `f1` vs `f2` plot side by side, one from the pair grid and the other from a single strip plot.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because it did help me solve my problem, but I'm still opening issue in Seaborn nonetheless, because I find the behavior "surprising", at least. I'll post a comment with the outcome.

Comment: I find it more surprising that using the `hue=df.values` did produce a plot similar to the expected one at all. I would have expected to see a plot with 1 single point per plot as for each category there is only one value.